SwiftData background processing rather than @MainActor
I am using SwiftData but am running in UI performance issues.
I found a nice article on how to perform all operations in the background:
Using ModelActor in SwiftData
It seems to make sense, but I am having a problem with the code given, and cannot see how to fix it.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

public struct SharedDatabase {
    
    public static let shared: SharedDatabase = .init()

    public let schemas: [any PersistentModel.Type]
    public let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    public let database: any Database
    
    private init(
        schemas: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [
            Event.self,
            Category.self
        ],
        modelContainer: ModelContainer? = nil,
        database: (any Database)? = nil
    ) {
        self.schemas = schemas
        let schema = Schema(schemas)
        //let modelContainer = modelContainer ?? .forTypes(schemas)
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        
        do {
            let modelContainer = try modelContainer ?? ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
            self.modelContainer = modelContainer
            self.database = database ?? BackgroundDatabase(modelContainer: modelContainer)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

private struct DefaultDatabase: Database {
    static let instance = DefaultDatabase()

    // swiftlint:disable:next unavailable_function
    func withModelContext<T>(_ closure: (ModelContext) throws -> T) async rethrows -> T {
        assertionFailure("No Database Set.")
        fatalError("No Database Set.")
    }
}

@ModelActor
public actor ModelActorDatabase: Database {}

public class BackgroundDatabase: Database {
    private actor DatabaseContainer {
        private let factory: @Sendable () -> any Database
        private var wrappedTask: Task<any Database, Never>?
  
        fileprivate init(factory: @escaping @Sendable () -> any Database) {
            self.factory = factory
        }
  
        fileprivate var database: any Database {
            get async {
                if let wrappedTask {
                    return await wrappedTask.value
                }
                let task = Task {
                    factory()
                }
                self.wrappedTask = task
                return await task.value
            }
        }
    }

    private let container: DatabaseContainer

    private var database: any Database {
        get async {
            await container.database
        }
    }

    internal init(_ factory: @Sendable @escaping () -> any Database) {
        self.container = .init(factory: factory)
    }
  
    public func withModelContext<T>(_ closure: @Sendable @escaping (ModelContext) throws -> T)
      async rethrows -> T
    { try await self.database.withModelContext(closure) }
}


public protocol Database: Sendable {
    func withModelContext<T>(
        _ closure: @Sendable @escaping (
            ModelContext
        ) throws -> T
    )
    async rethrows -> T
}

extension ModelActor where Self: Database {
    public func withModelContext<T: Sendable>(
        _ closure: @Sendable @escaping (ModelContext) throws -> T
    ) async rethrows -> T {
        let modelContext = self.modelContext
        return try closure(modelContext)
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry public var database: any Database = DefaultDatabase.instance
}

extension Scene {
    public func database(_ database: any Database) -> some Scene {
        environment(\.database, database)
    }
}

extension View {
    public func database(_ database: any Database) -> some View {
        environment(\.database, database)
    }
}

There is a warning for Swift 6 on 'BackgroundDatabase' that "Non-final class 'BackgroundDatabase' cannot conform to 'Sendable'; use '@unchecked Sendable'; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode"
But the compiler has an error on:
self.database = database ?? BackgroundDatabase(modelContainer: modelContainer)

with "Cannot convert value of type 'ModelActorDatabase' to expected argument type '@Sendable () -> any Database'"
I tried to use a ModelActorDatabase(modelContainer: modelContainer), but to no avail, and I must be missing something stupid.
It seems like a nice solution as you can then just add them to the root view:
    .database(SharedDatabase.shared.database)
    .modelContainer(SharedDatabase.shared.modelContainer)


This looks very over-engineered. You don't need all this fluff. When you need to do stuff in the background, just create an instance of ModelActorDatabase and operate on its modelContext. The author of the linked article might have some misunderstandings. The sentence "My thought is that all methods of an actor are called on the thread the object is created on" is just false.

Thanks Sweeper. I tried that but I have the problem then that the data does not save and I get the "SwiftData.ModelContext: Unbinding from the main queue. This context was instantiated on the main queue but is being used off it. ModelContexts are not Sendable, consider using a ModelActor."

Can you show a [mre]? It sounds like you are not isolated to the model actor when using the model actor's context. You should only access the model actor's context when isolated to that actor.

Have a look at my answer here and observe how the run method there is different from withModelContext in your code. The closure should be (isolated ModelActorDatabase).

ModelActor is for when you want to respond to something non-UI and modify SwiftData. E.g. in Apple's Backyard Birds sample they monitor StoreKit transactions in the background. https://github.com/apple/sample-backyard-birds/blob/main/Multiplatform/Shop/BirdBrain.swift

Show us your UI code and we might be able to tell you why it is slow. E.g. maybe you are mistakenly allocating heap objects in body. Or maybe you are saving manually too often instead of relying on auto-save when the app suspends.

@Sweeper I implemented your solution in the answer you quoted and that works perfectly
